# Format JSON date in JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp

I'm updating AJAX response using JSON taglib with this-

```
<json:property name="shipDate" value="Date is ${shippingDate}"></json:property>
```

But I want to format the shippingDate in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

Is it possible to format date while setting json property?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `fmt` tag lib. It has a `formatDate` tag to do that.

Comment: Thanks. How would I use the format tag within <json:property> tag in the code above though?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would use the `formatDate` with a `var` attribute, then reference that var value with EL, ex. `${var-name}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to format dates in JSP's using Java's tags:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatDate value="${shippingDate}" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy"/>
```

Update: You can also assign the output of  to a JSP var and use elsewhere in your JSP like so:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${shippingDate}" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy" var="formattedShippingData" />

<label>Shipping Date: </label> ${formattedShippingData}
```